# Regal Force and Cyclonic Rift

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

I have 2 green creatures out and I cast Regal Force. My opponent responds by overloading Cyclonic Rift. Do I draw 3, 1, or 0 cards and does Regal Force get bounced ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arqade. Just to make sure, you are talking about the [Duels of the Planeswalkers](http://store.steampowered.com/app/213850/) videogame to PC, consoles and mobile, right? As in, opposed to the actual Magic the Gathering card game in general. I don't remember the card set in that game by heart, so I just want to make sure you're in the right Stack Exchange site. ([Board & Card Games SE](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) would deal with the actual card game.)

Comment: Origin cards if it matters.  And states the answer should be the same IMO.  Unless there's a bug=)  They'll tell ya over there too tho, I imagine=)

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes the video game works the same as the MTG card game (it's supposed to).

**Once everything resolves, your Regal Force will remain on the field and you will have drawn 1 card.**

Here's the order of operations that occur:

1. You play Regal Force, it's placed on the stack.
2. Your opponent responds with Cyclonic rift. It's placed on the stack above Regal Force.
3. Both players choose not to play anything else.
4. Cyclonic Rift resolves. Your 2 creatures are returned to your hand. Regal Force is unaffected because it hasn't resolved and entered the field yet.
5. The stack contains only Regal Force. Both players decide not to play anything else.
6. Regal Force resolves. As it enters the battlefield, you draw cards equal to the green creatures you control (which is 1, because Regal Force counts itself).

Comment: Your answer should be based *on* the video game.

Comment: The video game is based on the card game (and WotC are good about keeping it consistent in my experience), so unless there's a bug it should be the same answer.

Comment: While this is most likely true, it's not impossible for the videogame to work differently from the card game. Either intentionaly or unintentionaly. (Magic isn't exactly an easy game to simulate with computers.)

Comment: @DJPirtu Not as difficult as you'd think, considering most of the games commit themselves to a few specific sets of cards. And elements such as the stack (probably the most important function in Magic), the order of operations (e.g. creature spell is cast -> creature spell resolves -> creature enters play and triggers ETB effects), and creatures including themselves for effects such as the one listed--all of these are among the simplest to program.

Comment: I'll accept whatever way the votes swing on this one, but I feel confident based on the above that there's no reason this situation would work differently from the card game.